# CSS – Form button isn't responding to styling

Tags: css

I have tried styling my form submit button, but it isn't responding to any CSS styling. I tried using its `class` individually and also `id` individually and even both the `class` and `id` together, but nothing is working. I've attached the code:

**HTML/PHP**

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
  $member_username = "username";
  $member_password = "pass****";

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

  if ($username == $member_username  && $password == $member_password) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header('Location: secret.php');
  } else {
    echo 'Incorrect username or password';
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel=stylesheet />
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>Topaz</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="index">
    <div class="indexcontainer">
      <h1>Topaz</h1>
      <div class="indexform">
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
          <input class="textbox" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" /><br /><br /><br />
          <input class="textbox" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br /><br />
          <input class="submit" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.submit {
  width: 200px;
}

#submit {
  width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Post the static code and create a demo of this please.

Comment: I don't think there should be a problem with the css or your html. Did you try to inspect that after you applied the element? did you try to refresh your page after changing the css? Can you try to create any demo for this problem?

Comment: I've tried php using external styling as you did and it is working

Comment: So this is the only bit of CSS thats not working? You're not providing us with a complete picture.

Comment: Your code looks basically OK. Have you tried using developer tools in Chrome (f12) or Firebug for firefox to inspect the element to see what styles are being applied to your element. Also make sure to flush the page cache to make sure the stylesheet is refreshed. Finally read up on CSS specificity rules.

Comment: also `<link href="style.css" rel=stylesheet />` should be `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably just relative pathing to the style sheet, hit F12 (for chrome, though may need to enable dev console, google if needed) and see whether the network panel or console panel show a 404 error for one or more files.

The actual css applies fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  -->
  <style>
    .submit{width:200px; color:red;}
  </style>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <title>Topaz</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="index">
    <div class="indexcontainer">
      <h1>Topaz</h1>
      <div class="indexform">
        <form action="index.php" method="POST">
          <input class="textbox" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <input class="textbox" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <input class="submit" id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Ensure that "style.css" is on the same level as the php or html file that is actually being hit, or use relative pathing.

Also its good form to validate your html and css, as unrelated syntax mistakes can break styling.

For html: https://validator.w3.org/

For css: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

But these likely wont be able to pickup on pathing issues, just syntax, so ensure you use the developer console for whatever browser your using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an inline style to have precedent over the external style sheet. Just use the  tag and then put in the in the head tag area.

```
<style>
  .submit {
    width: 200px;
  }
  #submit {
    width: 200px;
  }
</style>
```